# create multiple copies of staticresource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, staticresource

I have a template for items control shown below. I need separate instances of colorProvider for each item in the template. Each item in the items control requires a seperate instance of the Color Provider depending on the item it is bound to.
How do i create multiple copies of staticresource so that the staticresource is only available for that item.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MinHeight="250">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource chartSelector}">
                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                <v:ColorProvider x:Key="colorProvider"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: colorProvider resource is never used in your code.
Please describe how do you plan to use this resource.

Comment: It is referenced from the template that will be loaded in the contentpresenter. however as a workaround i managed to use the control tag object to get a reference back to the data that was supposed to initialize the colorprovider.

Comment: Sound like [x:Shared="False"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To return a new instance of a static resource each time it's requested, you can use the `x:Shared` attribute. This is documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx). From my experience with this attribute, you will **not** get Intellisense support when trying to set it. In your case, the attribute would need to be set on the `ColorProvider` in your Resources section, as follows.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource chartSelector}">
  <ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <v:ColorProvider x:Key="colorProvider" x:Shared=false />
  </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: Excellent! It works, and you were right about the intellisense as well!

Comment: This is one method to avoid the "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget" error if you have tried to add a non-shared resource twice.

Answer (score 0):

If resource value varies on data, you should use Binding in conjunction with value converter that will return the Color.